How do I make an Accordion layout which allows more than one item to be expanded and also scrolls when the items are many?
I currently have an Accordion layout which looks like this:

Note: the code for this can be seen here:  How do I position buttons in a vertical box layout?
In this Accordion, items are able to be expanded only one at a time.  And the item which is expanded is given all of the available space, no matter how much it needs.  If I add more items, the expanded one may not get enough space to display all of its content.
However, what I would like is an Accordion which allows for more than one item to be expanded at a time, like these samples:


I would even like the user to be able to expand all of them at once or none of them.
And since the user will be adding these accordion items at run time, I would like to have the possibility of the accordion to extend beyond the bottom of the window, with a scroll bar on the right to allow all of the items to be seen, like this:

Here, the scroll bar is part of the browser window, so it is provided outside the accordion.
Is there a way to customize the Kivy Accordion to...

allow for multiple items to be expanded or none at all?
allow for items to use exactly as much space as they need, no more, no less?
allow for many items, with a scroll bar to see them all?

Or do I need to create my own custom accordion widget?
